# MongoDB Java driver questions

Tags: mongodb

We are looking to upgrade our MongoDB from version 3.0.6 (with Java driver 3.0.4) to version 3.2.12.  (I know version 3.4.x is available, but I understand you can't go directly from 3.0.x to 3.4.x if you need to migrate data.)  A couple questions about the Java driver:

- Is Java driver 3.2.2 the right version that matches server 3.2.12?
- Is it supported for a newer Java driver version to communicate with an older server version?  In this case, it would be Java driver 3.2.2 talking to an older 3.0.6 server.  I compiled our client code with Java driver 3.2.2 today and saw no differences in the compiler output, so they seem compatible -- though this may not be supported in any case.
- Are there any issues with using Java driver 3.0.4 to talk to server 3.2.12?

Answer (score 0):

Most of these questions are answered in the [compatibility documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/java/#mongodb-compatibility) for this driver.

> Is Java driver 3.2.2 the right version that matches server 3.2.12?

Looks like yes, but you should make sure 3.2.2 is the most up to minor version for the 3.2 release (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/releases).

> Is it supported for a newer Java driver version to communicate with an older server version?

Yes, the 3.2 version of the driver can work with 3.0.X version of MongoDB.

> Are there any issues with using Java driver 3.0.4 to talk to server 3.2.12?

This table doesn't reference a 3.0 version of the MongoDB Java driver. Did you mean a different driver version?

Comment: Here's the full Java Driver Compatibility chart: https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#reference-compatibility-mongodb-java

Comment: Thank you, Adam.  I was not aware of this reference doc.  I did mean Java driver 3.0.4.  It is listed on a link on the URL you provided for additional Java drivers.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Happy to help. Credit where it's due, the more complete driver version link was provided by helmy. Feel free to upvote / accept if you feel its appropriate.